# SharePoint SPWeb.GetFile method with using server url and not using it at all

Tags: sharepoint

I notice that when we use **SPWeb.GetFile** method, we can pass the whole URL or only the part of the url.

Let's say my file exists in servername/sites/SiteA/DocumentLibrary/Folder/file.txt.
(i omit http)

SiteA = servername/sites/SiteA

```
   using (SPWeb oWebsiteFrom = new SPSite(SiteA).OpenWeb())
   {          
          SPFile oSrcSPFile = oWebsiteFrom.GetFile(ServerURL + "/" + DocLibrary+ "/" + Folder + "/" + fileName);
   }
```

This one is also OK to use without ServerURL in GetFile.

```
    using (SPWeb oWebsiteFrom = new SPSite(SiteA).OpenWeb())
   {          
          SPFile oSrcSPFile = oWebsiteFrom.GetFile(DocLibrary+ "/" + Folder + "/" + fileName);
   }
```

What is the difference between using serverURL and not using serverURL in GetFile method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is the same.

Lot of SharePoint methods(not all) using Url as parameter will call an internal method named "GetWebRelativeUrlFromUrl" to handle the Url

And below are the code of the methods invoked when you call SPWeb.GetFile

As you can see, the string will parse as UriScheme object and if your string is a ServerRelative uriScheme, the method will "convert" it to absolute url.

```
internal SPFile GetFile(string strUrl, byte iLevel)
{
    string webRelativeUrlFromUrl = this.GetWebRelativeUrlFromUrl(strUrl);
    if (webRelativeUrlFromUrl.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    return new SPFile(this, webRelativeUrlFromUrl, iLevel);
}


internal string GetWebRelativeUrlFromUrl(string strUrl)
{
    return this.GetWebRelativeUrlFromUrl(strUrl, true, true);
}



internal string GetWebRelativeUrlFromUrl(string strUrl, bool includeQueryString, bool canonicalizeUrl)
{
    string str;
    char[] chrArray;
    if (strUrl == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    if (strUrl.Length == 0)
    {
        return strUrl;
    }
    if (canonicalizeUrl || !includeQueryString)
    {
        strUrl = Utility.CanonicalizeFullOrRelativeUrl(strUrl, includeQueryString, out flag);
        canonicalizeUrl = 0;
        includeQueryString = 1;
    }
    UriScheme uriScheme = SPWeb.GetUriScheme(strUrl);
    if (uriScheme == UriScheme.ServerRelative)
    {
        string serverRelativeUrl = this.ServerRelativeUrl;
        if (!SPUtility.StsStartsWith(strUrl, serverRelativeUrl))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        str = strUrl.Substring(serverRelativeUrl.Length);
        if (str.Length > 0)
        {
            if (str.get_Chars(0) == 47)
            {
                return str.Substring(1);
            }
            if (uriScheme == UriScheme.Http || uriScheme == UriScheme.Https)
            {
                if (uriScheme == UriScheme.Http && strUrl.Contains(":80/"))
                {
                    strUrl = strUrl.Remove(strUrl.IndexOf(":80/"), ":80/".Length - 1);
                }
                bool flag2 = false;
                if (!SPUtility.StsStartsWith(strUrl, this.Url))
                {
                    using (SPSite sPSite = new SPSite(strUrl))
                    {
                        if (sPSite.ID != this.Site.ID)
                        {
                            throw new ArgumentException();
                        }
                        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(new Uri(strUrl));
                        uriBuilder.Scheme = sPSite.Protocol.TrimEnd(new char[] { 58 });
                        uriBuilder.Host = sPSite.HostName;
                        uriBuilder.Port = sPSite.Port;
                        strUrl = uriBuilder.Uri.ToString();
                    }
                    flag2 = SPUtility.StsStartsWith(strUrl, this.Url);
                }
                else
                {
                    flag2 = true;
                }
                if (flag2)
                {
                    str = strUrl.Substring(this.Url.Length);
                    if (str.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if (str.get_Chars(0) == 47)
                        {
                            return str.Substring(1);
                        }
                        throw new ArgumentException();
                        if (!strUrl.StartsWith("_"))
                        {
                            bool flag3 = true;
                            try
                            {
                                if (false || -1 == strUrl.IndexOf(58) || null != new Uri(strUrl))
                                {
                                    flag3 = false;
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                            }
                            if (!flag3)
                            {
                                throw new ArgumentException();
                            }
                        }
                        str = strUrl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for my late reply.